# MS SQL query - 2 tables same field - decide whitch to use

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple question.

I have 2 tables - Items and Items_Discount with the same field (actually two fields but for same use) Price and Price_Discount.

```
ItemID     Price     PriceDiscount
1234       2.10      1.90
2346       15.60     NULL
7527       3.20      2.80
```

What I need is to have the PriceDiscount value when it is not NULL, and Price value when it is.

What to do ?

Comment: I would rather save the amount of discount (`float`, `unsigned`, `default(0.0)`, and show `Price - Discount` to the user.

Comment: Why don't you just Set price = PriceDiscount where PriceDiscount IS null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) would seem to do exactly what you need;

```
SELECT COALESCE(PriceDiscount, Price) AS Price FROM mytable
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c689d/2).

Comment: How about Price = PriceDiscount where PriceDiscount IS null ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev If he wanted to update the table, that would be the thing to do. I assumed a SELECT was what the OP wants, since it gives the desired output without changing the table contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Select ItemID,IsNULL(PriceDiscout,Price) as Pricing
from <your tables>
```